# Install Wordpress on c9 local machine

Tags: localhost, desktop, cloud9-ide, workspace

I am trying to install some of the work spaces available in C9 web app on my local machine.

There is no reference to the work spaces on the local copy.  If I click on Dashboard it takes me to the online dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Standalone version doesn't have a dashboard, you need to start server with `-w /path/to/project` argument instead.

Or use desktop version based on node webkit https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/running-cloud9-desktop